# DuplicateKeyException: error code 11000 and error message 'E11000'

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

i want to update/replace document using id field only, i am using mongoTemplate.save(p, collection) method but i am getting DuplicateKeyException: error code 11000 and error message 'E11000'

```html
public class MongoDAO {
 
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("mongoTemplate")
 private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
 
 private static final String PERSON_COLLECTION = "person";

 public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
  return mongoTemplate;
 }
 
  public void update(Object p) {
  this.mongoTemplate.save(p, PERSON_COLLECTION);
 }
  
 }
```

This is my person DAO

```html
    public class PersonDAO{
      @Autowired
     MongoDAO mongoDAO;

      public void updatePerson(){
      
         //read
      Person p1 = mongoDAO.readById("1234");
      
      //update
      p1.setName("David");
        mongoDAO.update(p1);
      
     }
}
```

Person.java class

```html
package com.mongo.andy;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

public class Person {
 
 @Id
 private String id;
 @Field
 private String name;
 
 public String getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 
 

}
```

I simply want to get the object from mongodb change the values and update the document based on _id
Using mongooperation.save() or mongotemplate.save() i am getting below error

```html
com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: Person.person index: _id_ dup key: { : "5996f1d43b6af5c797a1cf4g" }'
 at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.convertBulkWriteException(BaseWriteOperation.java:236)
 at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.access$300(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
 at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:146)
 at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
 at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230)
 at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
 at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
 at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
 at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
 at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:333)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:319)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:289)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:255)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:192)
 at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$9.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1051)
 at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:479)
 at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:1046)
 at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:855)
 at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSaveVersioned(MongoTemplate.java:1001)
 at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:985)
 at com.mcmcg.dia.account.metadata.dao.MongoDAO.update(MongoDAO.java:105)
 at com.mcmcg.dia.account.metadata.service.AccountOALDService.mongotestapi(AccountOALDService.java:265)
 at com.mcmcg.dia.account.metadata.service.AccountOALDService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7f85f843.invoke(<generated>)
```

Please provide the solution and suggest if there is any other way to update/replace documents in mongodb using spring-data on the basis of id field only. I have large custom object and not interesting writing any queries for update.
I was able to do so in couchbase db using upsert(), finding similar way in mongodb.

Comment: Can you add your Person code snippet as well to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.mongoTemplate.save(p, PERSON_COLLECTION);` try with:

```
public void update(Object p) {
  BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
  mongoTemplate.getConverter().write(p, dbObject);
  mongoTemplate.upsert(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(((Person) p).getId())), 
      Update.fromDBObject(dbObject, "_id"), PERSON_COLLECTION);
}
```

The solution is similar to how the `upsert` method it is implemented in `MongoTemplate`.